# Bulk convert files extension using Python

Tags: python

Trying to develop a bulk webp to png converter using python.
Am using the webptools library (https://pypi.org/project/webptools/)
the documentation above only shows how to convert one file at each time and require user input of the file name.

So, what I am trying to do is to scan the folder for *.webp and then convert it to *.png with the original filename. I couldn't solve the output file names. I suppose with the current codes, it keeps overwriting the same file x.png, so it ended up with just 1 output file. I can't figure out how to fix this.

I am new to python. hope to get some guidance or help here. Thank you very much.

```
from webptools import dwebp
import os, glob
os.chdir("./images")  # working directory

webp_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.webp"):
    webp_list = file
    print([webp_list])


for files in webp_list:
    print(dwebp(input_image=webp_list, output_image="x.png", option="-o", logging="-v"))

# documentation - code allows only 1 input and 1 output
# print(dwebp(input_image="sample.webp", output_image="sample.png", option="-o", logging="-v"))
```

Comment: Replace `output_image` with a name dynamically generated using the original name.

Comment: i tried doing this
random_name = random.randint(0, 9)) 
output_image = random_name + ".png"
or
output_image = (random_name + ".png")
or
output_image = (random_name) + ".png"
couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do

```
webp_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.webp"):
    webp_list = file
    print([webp_list])
```

`webp_list` is name of last file which matches, rather list of file names. [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) itself

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match *pathname*(...)

so there is no need for such conhortion and you can simply do

```
webp_list = glob.glob("*.webp")
```

instead, then you need different output filename, for which I propose following solution

```
for filename in webp_list:
    outname = filename[:-4] + "png"
    dwebp(input_image=filename, output_image=outname, option="-o", logging="-v")
```

`filename[:-4]` means filename without 4 last characters (`webp` in this case), which is then concatenated with `png`.

Comment: thank you so much for the explaining on each section. got it working from your codes. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library before, so my suggestion is based just on how I guess it should work:

```
from webptools import dwebp
import os, glob
os.chdir("./images")  # working directory

webp_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.webp"):
    output_file = file[:-4] + 'png'
    dwebp(input_image=file, output_image=output_file, option="-o", logging="-v")
```